# Why doesn't rust complain when you drop a value that lives on the stack

Tags: rust

I'm learning about rust references and I am wondering about the `drop()` function.
In this example is `&Box<i32>` a reference to something on the stack or heap.

```rust
let y = 32; // `y` lives on the stack
drop(y); // why doesn't this complain
println!("{}", y); // this also doesn't complain
```

Comment: `i32` is a `Copy` type which means that when it would normally be moved, it's copied instead. The `drop` function just moves the value into it, but because it's `Copy`, it moves a copy of the value instead. `Copy` types must be trivially `Drop`-able for this reason.

Comment: It you use a `String` like `let y = String::new();` you can see that the expected error will happen.

Comment: I didn't mention the `Box` detail in my answer because I'm not really sure what you're asking. Your code doesn't create nor use a `Box` at all.

Comment: @cdhowie thanks, I left out another part of the code.. but your answer explained what I needed to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html) is not a special function.  All it does is take ownership of the value passed in, which is then destroyed when the function returns.  The documentation even says this:

> This function is not magic; it is literally defined as
>
> ```
> pub fn drop<T>(_x: T) { }
> ```
>
> Because `_x` is moved into the function, it is automatically dropped before the function returns.

What if you have a function that takes an `i32`?

```
fn example(_v: i32) { }
```

When you call this, the `i32` value you provide is *copied*, because `i32` implements the [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait.  This allows you to use the supplied value again later.

All `Copy` does is make it so that when a move of an implementing value is attempted, a bitwise copy is performed instead, which leaves the source value usable.

It should be clearer now why this doesn't cause a problem.  The value in `y` is copied into the `_x` argument of `drop()`.  Since it is copied and not moved, `y` is still usable.

If you change your code so that `y` holds a value of a type that does not implement `Copy`, you will see a compile-time error as you expect.

Comment: this makes perfect sense.